# Upgraded to 19.10 and network is unclaimed

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have upgraded to 19.10 UBUNTU and now the network shows as unclaimed (lshw -c network)

the product is RT8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gibabit Eth controller from Realtek.

what can i do to fix the issue

modprobe r8169 && desg | grep r8169 gives the following output

modprobe: FATAL: Module r8169 not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.0-20-generic

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe r8169 && dmesg | grep r8169`

Comment: I have added as per request. thank you for taking time to answer my query

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by going to realteks website and download the latest driver and manually installed it. now im online ...yuhu.